# NSURLSessionDataTask cancel and Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I've got NSURLSession, that downloads new user profiles from server, then for each profile downloads array of photos, and than stores in Core Data. Every time the user reaches this screen i stop downloading tasks, clear Core Data, than fill it again. The problem is, that cancel() function is async, so it manages to save some profiles AFTER i cleared Core Data. Moreover, these profiles can be without some data thanks to datatask cancel. 
So, the question is as follows - how to correctly finish download tasks and after that clear core data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `NSOperation` class for what you need.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/

You should wrap-up operation for downloading data into NSOperation class and before you add results to CoreData you can check if NSOperation was cancelled in between.

```
@interface DownloadOperation: NSOperation
@end

@implementation DownloadOperation
- (void)main {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [Server downloadDataFromServer:^(id results) {
             if (self.isCancelled == NO)
             {
                [CoreData saveResults:results];
             }
        }];
    }
}
@end
```

You add your operation to NSOperationQueue:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue= [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperation:[[DownloadOperation alloc] init]];
```

And you can cancel it by calling:

```
[operation cancel];
```

or canceling all operations:

```
[queue cancelAllOperations];
```

Comment: Well, i understand. But there is one more trouble. When the user fast leaves the collection view controller, and than loads it again - i delete objects from Core Data, but old controller instance continues building collection view for a few seconds before deinit, it tries to load removed models, which causes data fault and crash. How can i deal with this?